# SVG use element not showing paths

Tags: html, css, svg, sprite

I am trying to use SVG sprite technique to display single SVGS when I need them, and calling them via the 'use' element. I know this is slightly tricky because of the shadow DOM, but I can't figure out why my elements are not showing properly.

In my local dev build, which is different than this JSfiddle, the use element actually shows the SVG and the paths, but only as invisible shapes. No fill, or anything. Just invisible paths. I have it structured like this:

```
<nav class="nav-right">
    <div class="nav-right-left">
        <svg class="icon">
           <use class="icon-menu" xlink:href="#icon-menu"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The svg class 'icon' shows in the proper place but the use element shows outside of the div and down the page. Could this be because of user agent stylesheet having svg:not(:root) {overflow: hidden;}?

Can anyone look at the JSfiddle and attempt to explain why they are not displaying properly? https://jsfiddle.net/qs769rk6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case , the viewBox of each symbol is wrong, the first two arguments (which are at 0 0) , are not good . Both of these arguments is to move the mask to display the correct area, out in your case the mask is at the wrong place. For the #icon-menu, try to set the viewBox like this : viewBox="335 165 40 32".

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This worked perfectly. Can you explain the 335 and the 165? I thought that the "335 165" was left and top and should not be moved.

Comment: Also, I read an article saying that the first two arguments should rarely change from "0 0", and since my sprite is a line of SVG's I did not think that attribute would change.

Comment: The "0 0" thing would be true if your icons were aligned with the origin of the SVG (0,0), but your symbols aren't.  For example, the viewBox for your "icon-menu" is "127 0 40 32" which means that all the content is supposed to fit within the area (127,0) to (167,32).  But if you look at the coordinates of your path, you can see some of them are much larger than that (eg. 326.2,183.1). So it looks like most, if not all, of your symbol viewBoxes are wrong.

Comment: Oh okay, so how do I ensure the icons are aligned with the origin properly?  I set up the viewboxes from the coordinates of the SVG in illustrator when I set up the SVG

Comment: Actually, I understand it now. I took the SVG code and stripped out the display: none, and the symbol elements with the viewBox, and created an SVG file and opened it in illustrator. The elements were not on the artboard and were at the exact coordinates you mentioned. Any ideas on how to ensure they display at the proper (0,0) coordinates?